# How to suppress a section programmatically in Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

Is there a way to suppress/hide a section programmatically in Crystal Reports???

I need to suppress a section in Crystal Reports when the Change Text in one textbox

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this below code in your code behind file

> ```
>     CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument doc=your reportdocument;
>             doc.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["yourformulaname"].Text = "your value";
>
> //or you can directly set the visibility of your section from code behind on the basis of your business logic as
>  doc.ReportDefinition.Sections["sectionnameOrIndex"].SectionFormat.EnableSuppress = true;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

[image]Go to section expert.

Select your section.

On the right hand side you will notice a suppress checkbox. Check it.

Right beside the check box label you will see a formula button. Click on it. Now you can see a formula editor to write your logic.

In the formula editor write something like this

```
if {@yourformula}="1" then
    true //hide
else
    false //do not hide
```

{yourformula} can be replaced with any field you like.

If you want to set the value of your formula field from code behind then

CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument doc=your reportdocument;
doc.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["yourformulaname"].Text = "your value";

//or you can directly set the visibility of your section from code behind on the basis of your business logc as
doc.ReportDefinition.Sections["sectionnameOrIndex"].SectionFormat.EnableSuppress = true;